# How to copy the values of the first and last column of a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have code to copy the values from the pivot table and paste them onto a sheet:

the summary code is:

```
Sub Pivotcopy()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivottable2")
    .
    .
    .
    pt.TableRange2.Copy    
    Sheets("newsheet").Range("A20").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

However, this copies all the values. What I want is to copy only the first and last columns of the pivot table, i.e. the row labels column and the grand total column. After that I want to paste it in the "newsheet" sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You'd broken the back of it, just need to reference the two columns appropriately.

```
Sub Pivotcopy()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivottable2")

With pt.TableRange2
    Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(.Columns.Count)).Copy
End With

With Sheets("newsheet").Range("A20")
   .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   .Resize(3).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: works perfect, thank you very much. Is there any way to copy omitting the first 3 rows? because these do not contain important information (The filter being applied, a blank space, etc.)

Comment: Think the simplest way would be to delete the first 3 rows after pasting - see edit above.

Comment: Possibly not strictly needed, but as it suggests move rows below up (as opposed to left, which couldn't actually happen in this case!)